# How can I use window functions in later CTE's in Databricks SQL?

Tags: sql, databricks

Is there a way to use window functions in later CTE's in databricks?

Databricks SQL seems to be unable to use window functions that are defined in a CTE in later CTE's or select statements

Example:

```
with base as (
 select 
   *, 
   row_number() OVER(partition by col1, ORDER BY col2, col3) as primary_rank
 from table1
),
middle as (
 select *
 from base
 where primary_rank = 1
)
select ID, count(*) as n
from middle
group by ID
having n > 1
```

would result in the error `[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name primary_rank cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [base.col1, base.col2, etc...]`

Was hoping to use these window functions later on, and there's little to no documentation on this from databricks SQL side

Comment: I haven't run into this and can't comment on why this isn't working (it seems very odd that it isn't working). What I do want to say is that you can use `QUALIFY` in the same SQL to do the same thing `with middle as (SELECT * FROM table1 QUALIFY row_number() OVER(partition by col1, ORDER BY col2, col3) = 1) select ID, count(*) as n
from middle GROUP BY ID having n > 1`

Comment: That looks more like a bug , have you reported it?

Comment: @JNevill yeah that's true I forgot about that - I'll use that for now

Comment: @nbk I'm not able to find a decent place to report something like this...do you know of one?

Comment: Does the same issue arise if you just use derived tables instead of CTE?

Comment: @smoot you can report it at the community or raise a support ticket

Comment: @Stu I can make the first CTE a proper table and do the rest of the query fine after that